# Meta_search error with model associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, meta-search

I have these in my controller:

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
 def index
  @search = Account.search(params[:search])
  @accounts = @search.order("id desc").includes(:chef).page(params[:pagina]).per(10)
 end
end
```

My view:

```
<%= f.text_field :username_or_email_or_chef_name_contains %>
```

Works fine! But, when I search **based on email**, I got this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Accounts#index 
Mysql2::Error: Column 'id' in order clause is ambiguous: SELECT  `accounts`.`id` AS t0_r0, `accounts`.`chef_id` AS t0_r1,...
```

If I take off the **.includes(:chef)** of account controller, works fine.

**QUESTION**

Why this error? For performance reasons, I wouldn't like to remove the `include` from account controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accounts table and chefs table each have an `id` column, so MySQL doesn't know which of those columns it should order by.  Try specifying the table name in the order by clause:

```
@accounts = @search.order("accounts.id desc").includes(:chef).page(params[:pagina]).per(10)
```